# Dropbox API Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-entry

This question would be related mostly to Android, however it is a little more general.

I can upload and download files using `getFile` and such API calls, however, I am trying to access a directory which exists already on Dropbox and list it's content.

Using the API, I would like to be able to reference the directory at path '/path/to/dir/' and list all the `Entry` objects inside it using `Entry.contents`.

I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
Entry dir = new Entry();
dir.path = "/path/to/dir";
Log.d(TAG, "isDir ? " + Boolean.toString(dir.isDir));
for (Entry entry : dir.contents) {
    Log.d(TAG, entry.filename());
}
```

The directory is not empty. `isDir` returns `false` and no filenames are printed.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to use the search method?

All I want is the list of files in an existing directory.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the metadata function:

```
String path2Dir = "path/to/dir";
Entry dir = mDropboxApiInstance.metadata(path2Dir, null, true, null);
List<Entry> contents = dir.contents;
for (Entry dropboxFile : contents){
  // do stuff with remote file's data
}
```